# Preserve CommentedSeq flow_style after in-place assignment

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I would like to assign new values to a CommentedSeq object in place to preserve its flow style. However, such an operation leads to `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'slice' and 'int'`.

Does this mean CommentedSeq does not support in-place assignment, the most basic feature for a Python list?

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

y = YAML()
x = y.seq([1, 2])
x.fa.set_flow_style()
x[:] = [3, 4]


    451         # type: (Any, Any) -> None
    452         # try to preserve the scalarstring type if setting an existing key to a new value
--> 453         if idx < len(self):
    454             if isinstance(value, string_types) and \
    455                not isinstance(value, ScalarString) and \

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'slice' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fail to indicate which (outdated) version of `ruamel.yaml` you have been using, nor give a reason why you are not using the latest version.

`CommentedSeq` is not a list or a subclass thereof, it is a sub-subclass of `MutableSequence` (from `collections.abc`) and although I would not call in place slice assigment the most basic freature for a Python list in any event, it certainly is not something that is supported by `MutableSequences`.

However that does not mean that `CommentedSeq` does not support in-place [slice] assignment:

```
$ mktmpenv -p /opt/python/3.6/bin/python
Running virtualenv with interpreter /opt/python/3.6/bin/python
Using base prefix '/opt/python/3.6'
New python executable in /home/venv/tmp-2aaa383875f076d7/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
This is a temporary environment. It will be deleted when you run 'deactivate'.
(tmp-2aaa383875f076d7) $ pip install ruamel.yaml
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, http://localhost:4040/anthon/dev/+simple/
Collecting ruamel.yaml
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/77/51/f4314ebd8a3ec4989a3b3339a47382d87f251e5b82f2b7852a67649bc862/ruamel.yaml-0.15.64-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (645kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 655kB 3.5MB/s 
Installing collected packages: ruamel.yaml
Successfully installed ruamel.yaml-0.15.64
(tmp-2aaa383875f076d7) $ python
Python 3.6.6 (default, Jul 28 2018, 11:00:00) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ruamel.yaml import YAML
>>> 
>>> y = YAML()
>>> x = y.seq([1, 2])
>>> x.fa.set_flow_style()
>>> x[:] = [3, 4]
>>> print(x)
[3, 4]
>>> import sys
>>> y.dump(x, sys.stdout)
[3, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks! I was using 0.15.37. Updating to the latest release fixed the issue.